# Enviar información a un Guard en Angular

Tags: angular

necesito obtener informacion en un Guard, sobre cada componente, he buscado documentacion pero no encuentro algo sobre ello, por lo que no se si es posible
hacer lo que busco

Este es mi codigo
Guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PermisosDerechosService } from '../services/permisos-derechos.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ValidarAccesoGuard implements CanActivate{
  
  public opc;
  constructor(private permisosService: PermisosDerechosService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute){
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.opc = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>{
      console.log(this.opc);
      return this.permisosService.validarAccesoPermisos()
      
  }
  
}
```

Este es la parte del routing donde intento enviar informacion

```
const routesAsignacionPermisos: Routes = [
{path:'dashboard', component:DashboardComponent,
    children: [
      {path: 'Permisos',
      data : {datos: 'prueba'}, 
      canActivate: [ValidarAccesoGuard],
      component: PermisosDerechosComponent},
    ]
}]
```

Necesito hacer esto ya que varios componentes utilizaran el Guard, pero cada opcion tendra unos parametros diferentes por ejemplo menu: 1, opcion: 1
para validar permisos sobre cada opcion, intento hacerlo en un solo Guard para no tener que hacer uno para cada opcion, hay alguna manera de obtener datos dinamicos en el Guard dependiendo el componente que lo está utilizando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que hacerlo dentro del `canActivate`

```js
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > {
  console.log(route.data);//<===Aqui esta lo que buscas
  return this.permisosService.validarAccesoPermisos()

}
```

Comment: Perfecto, no lo habia visto, muchas gracias